# .NET Regex to detect and split the strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to split the following strings into segments.

```
#if [Customer.OrderQuantity] > 5 #then 1000 #if [Customer.OrderQuantity] < 5 #then 500 #else 100


 1st Segment: #if [Customer.OrderQuantity] > 5 #then 1000
 2nd Segment: #if [Customer.OrderQuantity] < 5 #then 500
 3rd Segment: #else 100
```

Your suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this post was voted down. It would be more help if you can leave a comment.

Comment: Was not me, but I assume the downvoter wanted you to show some effort. Like, what have you tried?

Comment: Not necessary to leave a comment it is obvious, this post shows no effort and is only asking for a solution (OK you wrote suggestion). [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This kind of splitting is not reliable with a regex because the regex has to know the underlying syntax. I'd consider using ANTLR

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have tried this one: (#if)(?:(?!#if).)*(#then)(?:(?!#if|#else).)*

Comment: In fact, it is working but I have a sinking feeling about this expression. Probably, I am overdoing it.

Comment: In fact, it was my mistake that I was in a rush and I have failed to present what I tried before. Anyway, thanks for your comments and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is producing the output you want

```
string source = "#if [Customer.OrderQuantity] > 5 #then 1000 #if [Customer.OrderQuantity] < 5 #then 500 #else 100";

string[] result = Regex.Split(source, @"\s*(?=#(?:if|else))");

foreach (string a in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

But I am guessing at some points, I have no idea if this is doing what you want for other cases.

Comment: I'd put in the space before the lookahead so it's not left trailing, but yeah, this was what I was thinking.

Comment: @stema ... Thanks Let me try it out

Comment: @stema ... You hit the nail on the head. The expression that you used is compact and clear. A lot better than mine.